# How can I delete a bunch of shared folders from my google drive?

Tags: google-drive, permissions, google-drive-sharing

I am not listed as a collaborator or owner of any of these files. When I click on the "Share" button, my name isn't listed anywhere in there. But somehow they're all shared with me. How can I get rid of them (while still allowing the current collaborators to access them)?

I tried just deleting the folder, but they still appear in my "Shared Files".

This is nearly identical to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67161/how-to-remove-myself-from-shared-google-drive-folder), but the proposed solutions do not work for me (dragging the file into the trash still shows them in my search results).

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same or a similar issue. First I did most of what the people recommended in the link you posted above but it still showed 40+ shared files that I wasn’t connected to anymore so, I:

- logged out
- closed my browser/quit my browser (I use Chrome)
- restarted the browser
- re-logged in

Essentially it was the digital equivalent of unplugging it and plugging it back in/turning it off and on. Have you tried that yet?